# Getting null passed to the d3.selection.on function

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, choropleth

I'm trying to combine two examples from the d3 examples on bl.ocks ([Choropleth](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) and [click-to-zoom](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590)). Presently I have this (response is an AJAX response from my backend that passes in things like us.json that I need for displaying the choropleth).

Style

```
.background {
    fill: transparent;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#states {
    fill: #aaa;
}

#state-borders {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
response = parseJSON(response);
var us = response['us'];
var data = response['data'];
var reportID = response['reportID'];
var thresholds = response['thresholds'];
var colorScheme = response['colorScheme'];
var max = response['max'];
var options = response['options'];
var name = options['name'];
var width = 900, height = 500, centered;

//define the display threshold
var color = d3.scale.threshold()
    .domain(thresholds)
    // .range(["#f2f0f7", "#dadaeb", "#bcbddc", "#9e9ac8", "#756bb1", "#54278f"]); //purple
    .range(colorScheme); //all colors

var rateById = {};
for(var i in data){
    rateById[data[i]['id']] = +data[i]['value'];
}

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(1070)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("#" + rowID + " .choropleth:nth-of-type(" + (parseInt(options['i']) + 1) + ")").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

var g = svg.append("g");      

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(rateById[d.id]); });

g.append("g")
    .attr("id", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)

g.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
    .attr("id", "state-borders")
    .attr("d", path);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", clicked);

function clicked(d){
    console.log(typeof d);
    var x, y, k;

    if(d && centered !== d){
        var centroid = path.centroid(d);
        x = centroid[0];
        y = centroid[1];
        k = 4;
        centered = d;
    }else{
        x = width / 2;
        y = height / 2;
        k = 1;
        centered = null;
    }

    console.log(x + "\n" + y + "\n" + k + "\n" + centered);

    g.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
        .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
}
```

I put the `console.log(typeof d);` to check if the status of the parameter being passed to the click function and find that it's `null` but if I take out the block that adds in the county lines then the click function is passed the appropriate value and the zoom function works as expected. I tried rearranging the various blocks that are adding in the SVG elements' order but without any success. I couldn't find any documentation as to where exactly the parameter passed to the click function comes from so I don't know what could cause it to be null.

Comment: The `d` refers to the data bound to the element that's clicked, and you're not binding any data to the `rect` elements.

Comment: But if I take out the block that creates the counties then it works fine and that block's presence shouldn't affect whether or not the rect has data

Comment: No, it shouldn't, and I don't see how you get that behaviour. Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: What I provided in the JS section above is all of the code associated with displaying the choropleth. The only thing missing is the data in `us` and `data` which are us.json and id/value pairs like in the data file contained in the choropleth bl.ock. colorScheme by default is the colors contained in the commented out line above it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving the block that created the counties

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "counties")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(rateById[d.id]); })
    .on("click", clicked);
```

To the end (right before I define the `clicked` function) and putting the click event handler on that element instead of the rect.